# Testing UI with locust

Tags: selenium-webdriver, performance-testing, locust

I have been able to load test the backend APIs of my web application using locust in my CIT environment.

Since the CIT is a protected environment, I had to manually login with my user in CIT environment via browser and copy the required **request headers** and use them in code to send successful requests.

My current code:

```
import time
from locust import HttpUser, task, between

class TestUser(HttpUser):

    wait_time = between(0.1, 0.2)

    @task
    def client_dashboard(self):
        print('load testing "Client Dashboard" screen')

        client_req_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJMT3Etc0JueEtvYkZHbWNzaU9FT0pzV3VHSjB5MEJreDlISU5xUjZQbUEwIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2MDiJ9.xNIZqrZjvVkauLUVHv1dSb9vqOHtb1-kfBG94hZqGqhXWaK06IfYuYsFJlpmSa4mcauW',
                        'realm': 'Client1'
                        }

        self.client.get("/order-service/orders/summary/12", headers=client_req_headers)
       
        self.client.get("/order-service/clients/12/", headers=client_req_headers)


    def on_start(self):
        print('In on_start method')

    def on_stop(self):
        print('In on stop method')
```

I am new to locust and so far I have been able to identify that with locust I can send many concurrent requests by defining tasks in my User classes. Whatever behavior I define in my tasks will be load tested.

I wanted to know if I can also check the UI flow using locust. i.e. Open the login page via code, Enter the credentials and submit. Then directed to the dashboard page on successful login and navigate the different links (Our frontend is an SPA (single page application) built using **Quasar**)

Does locust provide this functionality?
Would I have to include another python library for this case like selenium etc. ?
What would be the recommended way to achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Locust doesn't have built-in support for anything like that. It's primarily designed for just API and endpoint testing. But it's flexible enough to run any code in an orchestrated and distributed manner so it is possible. There are community modules that should be able to get you what you want. I haven't tried it but you could look at this:

https://github.com/nickboucart/realbrowserlocusts

Comment: Thanks for the response. realbrowserlocusts isn't compatible with locust versions > 1 and has not been updated for quite some time now as explained in the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890209/headless-browser-and-locust-io